# "Stylesheet could not be loaded" en Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Me ha salido un error en Firefox a la hora de probar un sitio que estoy creando, el error dice `"Stylesheet Could Not Be Loaded"` y solo pasa cuando utilizo `Firefox` pero lo raro es que algunas partes de la hoja de estilos si carga como por ejemplo el color de fondo del footer y del main, además cuando modifico la hoja de estilos desde Firefox esta cambia, modifiqué cosas en la hoja de estilo y todo pero cuando vuelvo a ejecutar el sitio es como si los cambios nunca se hubiesen hecho, es más, también modifiqué el estilo directo desde Firefox y guardé esa hoja de estilos pero sigue sin "reconocerla" digamos, ¿alguien sabe a qué se debe esto?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Te da algún error más? ¿Por ejemplo algún error 404? ¿Tienes más de una hoja de estilos referenciadas a tu HTML? ¿Podrías indicar cual es el CSS que estás utilizando actualmente?

Comment: Lo primero que deberías hacer es **mirar la consola del navegador** para saber con qué estás tratando.

Comment: @Error404 Hola, no no tengo algún otro error y tengo 2 hojas de estilos, una propia y la otra de Bootstrap pero ya se solucionó ni sé como la verdad ya que se solucionó solo. Estoy usando las 2 hojas de estilos por cierto, saludos y gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Hola, sí, miré la consola pero además de eso no había otro error y como dije en los otros comentarios se terminó arreglando solo, no sé por qué habrá pasado eso la verdad, saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Vamos por partes:

> el error dice "Stylesheet Could Not Be Loaded"

Este error lo que quiere decir es que hay algún recurso que no es ha cargado correctamente. Puede ser que dentro de la hoja de css se pida un recurso externo como por ejemplo una topografía y esta no se cargue correctamente. Un motivo puede ser porque la url a la tipografía esta mal o el servidor esta caído.

Para saber esto te recomiendo abrir la ventana de desarrolladores de firefox y mirar si hay un error de algún tipo a la hora de descargar los recursos. Por ejemplo un 404.

> modifiqué cosas en la hoja de estilo y todo pero cuando vuelvo a ejecutar el sitio es como si los cambios nunca se hubiesen hecho

Creo que cuando vueles a recargar la página los recursos se vuelven a descargar sobrescribiendo el cambio.

> también modifiqué el estilo directo desde Firefox y guardé esa hoja de estilos pero sigue sin "reconocerla" digamos

Posiblemente sea porque firefox carga la hoja de estilos desde la cache. Busca alguna herramienta para limpiar la cache de la página.

Al no tener más datos no puedo responder de una manera más precisa. Saludos!

Comment: Hola, no tenía ningún error 404, ese `Stylesheet could not be found` se debía a la hoja de estilos de Bootstrap, lo que pasaba era que aunque modificara mi hoja de estilos que había creado cuando miraba en consola las modificaciones no aparecían incluso después de volver a ejecutar la página, cerrar y volver a abrir el navegador, etc, no sé qué habrá sido pero se ha solucionado solo, gracias por la respuesta, saludos.